# Clean way to check for Null in Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, lambda

I have seen a lot of questions on this but was not able to find a clean solution:

I have the following lambda expression:

```
var result = Store.FirstOrDefault(x.Products.Coupon[0] == 100);
```

I would like to check for null for the Coupon collection to check to see if its not null and then compare the first coupon with the value 100. What would be a clean way to check for NULL for Coupon in the lambda? I do not want to use an extension method to check for null. I would like to do the check inline.

Comment: Unfortunately in linq-sql there is no guaranteed order for the checks so you can't really check for null and then make a check against a null object because it will throw an error. linq-objects supports this though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var result = Store.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Products.Coupon != null && x.Products.Coupon.Any() && x.Products.Coupon[0] == 100);
```

Comment: @TravisJ user1527762 did not mention anything about needing to support Linq to Sql in the question.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, this is not linq to sql but linq to objects lambda